# create a geotiff datastore in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, geoserver-rest-api

im able to create a data store in geoserver but when i try to access it in the geoserver admin console i get this error :

can't load chosen data, verify that the loader module is installed (sorry for this horrible traduction because the error message is in french)

[image]

and this is the code :

```
   public function createGeoTiffDataStore($datastoreName, $workspaceName, $location) {
    $data = '<dataStore>
                  <name>'.htmlentities($datastoreName, ENT_COMPAT).'</name>
                  <type>GeoTIFF</type>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <connectionParameters>
                    <entry key="url">file:'.htmlentities($location, ENT_COMPAT).'</entry>
                    <entry key="namespace">'.htmlentities($workspaceName, ENT_COMPAT).'</entry>
                  </connectionParameters>
            </dataStore>';
    return $this->runApi('workspaces/' . urlencode($workspaceName). '/datastores', 'POST', $data);
}


private function runApi($apiPath, $method = 'GET', $data = '', $contentType = 'text/xml') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->serverUrl.'rest/'.$apiPath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username.":".$this->password);
    if ($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    } else if ($method == 'DELETE' || $method == 'PUT') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    }

    if ($data != '') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Content-Type: $contentType",
                'Content-Length: '.strlen($data))
        );
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $rslt = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    if ($info['http_code'] == 401) {
        return 'Access denied. Check login credentials.';
    } else {
        return $rslt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to load the GeoTiff with the UI instead of the REST API to check if issue is from your code or from the GeoServer install?

Comment: I will try thx il give a feedback as soon as pssible

Comment: ok manual geotiff datastore its ok, i dont know if the problem come from my xml structure that geoserver can't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i guess i found the problem :

1) i change my xml to this :

```
<coverageStore>
              <name>'.htmlentities($datastoreName, ENT_COMPAT).'</name>
              <type>GeoTIFF</type>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <connectionParameters>
              <entry key="url">file:'.htmlentities($location, ENT_COMPAT).'</entry>
              <entry key="namespace">'.htmlentities($workspaceName, ENT_COMPAT).'</entry>
              </connectionParameters>
        </coverageStore>
```

2) i change my url to target de coverageStore like this :

```
return $this->runApi('workspaces/' . urlencode($workspaceName). '/coveragestores', 'POST', $data);
```

so the problem was that im using the wrong xml schema and im targeting the wrong api correct me if im wrong

best regards.

Comment: Could you mark your own answer as correct, by clicking the green check mark?